# Pixelart style render in blender

Tags: rendering, pixel-art

I want to create pixelart sprites for my game, but instead of drawing them, I want to render them with blender. Is it possible to make render like these http://timmaxwell.org/pages/retrorenderer/ ? I think about this flat shading and outline black lines.

Comment: Use toon shaders and freestyle, for cycles

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at this: http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/65505
or this: http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/44982

They are both using Freestyle for the lines, and Eight_Bit blending has no anti-aliasing. But you can find all that out with a look at the .blend files.